# edtitext default values comes in emulator not on device

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-edittext

I am having a weird problem, I have few `EditText` boxes in xml and I have given them default values. I am using shared preferences too wherein I save values entered by user.

Problem is that in Emulator `EditText` works fine but on real physical device values are empty, am i missing something???

```
  <EditText
       android:id="@+id/etTRQPO"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:ems="10"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:text="15">
  </EditText>
```

java code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Getacc extends Activity {
    Button save6;

    EditText edtTRQPO, edtTRQGE, edtTRQFW, edtTRQGR, edtTRQBN, edtTRQLT,
            edtTRQPP, edtTRQCG;
    int tV, tW, tX, counterAC;
    String tsTRQPO, tsTRQGE, tsTRQFW, tsTRQGR, tsTRQBN, tsTRQLT, tsTRQPP,
            tsTRQCG;
    public static String FILE1 = "MyPrefsFile";
    SharedPreferences abcPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.getacc);
        save6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btGoresult);
        edtTRQPO = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQPO);
        edtTRQGE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQGE);
        edtTRQFW = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQFW);
        edtTRQGR = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQGR);
        edtTRQBN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQBN);
        edtTRQLT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQLT);
        edtTRQPP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQPP);
        edtTRQCG = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQCG);

        abcPref = getSharedPreferences(FILE1, 0);
        edtTRQPO.setText(abcPref.getString("tsTRQPO", ""));
        edtTRQGE.setText(abcPref.getString("tsTRQGE", ""));
        edtTRQFW.setText(abcPref.getString("tsTRQFW", ""));
        edtTRQGR.setText(abcPref.getString("tsTRQGR", ""));
        edtTRQBN.setText(abcPref.getString("tsTRQBN", ""));
        edtTRQLT.setText(abcPref.getString("tsTRQLT", ""));
        edtTRQPP.setText(abcPref.getString("tsTRQPP", ""));
        edtTRQCG.setText(abcPref.getString("tsTRQCG", ""));

        save6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ((!edtTRQPO.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        && (!edtTRQGE.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        && (!edtTRQFW.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        && (!edtTRQGR.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        && (!edtTRQBN.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        && (!edtTRQLT.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        && (!edtTRQPP.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        && (!edtTRQCG.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    counterAC =1;
                    abcPref = getSharedPreferences(FILE1, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = abcPref.edit();
                    editor.putString("tsTRQPO", edtTRQPO.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("tsTRQGE", edtTRQGE.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("tsTRQFW", edtTRQFW.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("tsTRQGR", edtTRQGR.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("tsTRQBN", edtTRQBN.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("tsTRQLT", edtTRQLT.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("tsTRQPP", edtTRQPP.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("tsTRQCG", edtTRQCG.getText().toString());
                    editor.putInt("counterac", counterAC);
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast message = Toast.makeText(Getacc.this,
                            "Values are saved", 2000);
                    message.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                    message.show();
                    Intent opentime = new Intent("com.sports.sport.TIME");
                    startActivity(opentime);
                    onPause();
                } else {
                    Toast failz = Toast.makeText(Getacc.this,
                            "Values are not Entered", 2000);
                    failz.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                    failz.show();
                }
            };
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: are you setting `SharedPrefrences` values in `EditText`?

Comment: post your code at where you save value for EditText

Comment: you can't get it because at onCreate you are retrieving your Data from Shared Preferences so it will be null ..

Comment: you mean :-     edtTRQPO.setText(abcPref.getString("tsTRQPO", ""));

Comment: how many time you have tried to run app on real device??

Comment: so you mean to say that i need to put default values in sharedpreferences like tis :--------edtTRQPO.setText(abcPref.getString("tsTRQPO", "15"));

Comment: @monikasingh no my means is not something like that

Comment: if values are reset by sharedpreferences then it should reset on emulator too..

Comment: @PiyushGupta check my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first time when you will run app on real device it will show default values, not values from SharedPreferences because values in SharedPreferences are empty. When you will open app for second if SharedPreferences have empty values, EditText will show empty values from SharedPreferences. You need to Apply some value check like

```
 if(user_entered_values_in_edittext){
    //Store values in SharedPreferences otherwise not.
 }

 // On app resume - inside onResume() or onCreate()
 if(SharedPreferences have empty value or no value){
    //Show your EditText default value that you have defined in xml file.
 }
```

Corrected Getacc.java file...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Getacc extends Activity {
   Button save6;

   EditText edtTRQPO, edtTRQGE, edtTRQFW, edtTRQGR, edtTRQBN, edtTRQLT,
        edtTRQPP, edtTRQCG;
   int tV, tW, tX, counterAC;
   String tsTRQPO, tsTRQGE, tsTRQFW, tsTRQGR, tsTRQBN, tsTRQLT, tsTRQPP,
        tsTRQCG;
   public static String FILE1 = "MyPrefsFile";
   SharedPreferences abcPref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.getacc);
    save6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btGoresult);
    edtTRQPO = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQPO);
    edtTRQGE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQGE);
    edtTRQFW = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQFW);
    edtTRQGR = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQGR);
    edtTRQBN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQBN);
    edtTRQLT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQLT);
    edtTRQPP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQPP);
    edtTRQCG = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTRQCG);

    abcPref = getSharedPreferences(FILE1, 0);

    // First get All values stored in SharedPreferences 
      tsTRQPO = abcPref.getString("tsTRQGE", null);
      tsTRQGE = abcPref.getString("tsTRQGE", null);
      tsTRQFW = abcPref.getString("tsTRQFW", null);
      tsTRQGR = abcPref.getString("tsTRQGR", null);
      tsTRQBN = abcPref.getString("tsTRQBN", null);
      tsTRQLT = abcPref.getString("tsTRQLT", null);
      tsTRQPP = abcPref.getString("tsTRQPP", null);
      tsTRQCG = abcPref.getString("tsTRQCG", null);

      // Check if values are not null
      if(tsTRQPO != null && tsTRQGE != null && tsTRQFW != null && tsTRQGR!= null && tsTRQBN != null && tsTRQLT != null && tsTRQPP != null && tsTRQCG != null){
          edtTRQPO.setText(tsTRQPO);
          edtTRQGE.setText(tsTRQGE);
          edtTRQFW.setText(tsTRQFW);
          edtTRQGR.setText(tsTRQGR);
          edtTRQBN.setText(tsTRQBN);
          edtTRQLT.setText(tsTRQLT);
          edtTRQPP.setText(tsTRQPP);
          edtTRQCG.setText(tsTRQCG);

      }else{
        //Do nothing.. EditText will show Default values defined in xml file
      }

    save6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if ((!edtTRQPO.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    && (!edtTRQGE.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    && (!edtTRQFW.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    && (!edtTRQGR.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    && (!edtTRQBN.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    && (!edtTRQLT.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    && (!edtTRQPP.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    && (!edtTRQCG.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counterAC =1;
                abcPref = getSharedPreferences(FILE1, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = abcPref.edit();
                editor.putString("tsTRQPO", edtTRQPO.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("tsTRQGE", edtTRQGE.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("tsTRQFW", edtTRQFW.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("tsTRQGR", edtTRQGR.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("tsTRQBN", edtTRQBN.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("tsTRQLT", edtTRQLT.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("tsTRQPP", edtTRQPP.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("tsTRQCG", edtTRQCG.getText().toString());
                editor.putInt("counterac", counterAC);
                editor.commit();
                Toast message = Toast.makeText(Getacc.this,
                        "Values are saved", 2000);
                message.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                message.show();
                Intent opentime = new Intent("com.sports.sport.TIME");
                startActivity(opentime);
                onPause();
            } else {
                Toast failz = Toast.makeText(Getacc.this,
                        "Values are not Entered", 2000);
                failz.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                failz.show();
            }
        };
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences are saved in cache. If you relaunch your app from IDE, shared preferences are not cleared. If you want to clear it you should

1. uninstall app
2. go to seettings > programs > find your program > clear cache.

Only then it's empty. So maybe your problem is that you have old values on emulator and on device it's new (or vice versa)

Comment: i wiped data on emulator and values were by default present, its wiered because on device no default values.

Answer (score 0):

At first time, there is no SharedPreferences in the application so `abcPref.getString("tsTRQPO", "")` and others result into empty default value given here. Once you have saved the data by filling all edit texts you will get it proper from next time.

For checking, try to put some default value while fetching data from SharedPreferences. For ex `edtTRQPO.setText(abcPref.getString("tsTRQPO", "15"));` and check whether it loads value 15 first time.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of you'r trying to get value in OnCreate method from SharedPreferences which is currently has blank means null,
now look, when you start your app it will execute OnCreate methode first where you trying to get value from sharedPreferences, when your save value on `save6.setOnClickListener`

what is it?

note : get value after save in sharedPreferences